# How to count the total number of unique ID with the same conditions using python

Tags: python

How to count the total number of unique ID with the same conditions using python?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you doing some kind of image processing?

Comment: Firstly, I created a new column that gives me 1 if there is a country and 0 if there is no country. Next, I code df[(df["gps_count"]==1.0)].groupby(['uid']).nunique().count()  to find the number of unique IDs with only 1. Likewise, I use the same code to find how many unique IDs with only 0. However, when I try to use this code df[(df["gps_count"]==0) & (df["gps_count"]==1)].groupby(['uid']).nunique().count() to find the number of unique IDs with mixed of 1 & 0 the output it gave me is 0. But it is wrong because there should be some unique IDs with mixed of 1&0

Comment: Please provide sample data and reproducible code of what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['uid'].unique()
```

it may solve your problem.